# Mount Current Directory in Containrer using docker file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am new to docker i  want to  mount current directory in container  and run command.

USING DOCKER FILE

mount current directory in a folder eg files

EG:

```
FROM ubuntu  As tuttt
VOLUME [ %cd% ]
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
RUN ls
```

Comment: in the dockrefile you can only specify the volume destination, not the source.

Answer (score 2):

Volumes are mounted when you run a container. Dockerfile is the definition of the steps to build an image. From the image you run a container.

You can build your image (remove the VOLUME declaration since it is not useful in your case) and then you run it with:

```
docker run -v <host_path>:<container_path> <image_tag>
```

Comment: how to do it with in docker file .there is a voulume keyword ..does it do hte same job

Comment: No. It doesn't do the same thing. Please read the  Dockerfile reference available online. It explains very well the concept. In a few words: it's not that useful